# MySQL 5.5 - Can't see Triggers

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot see any of the triggers on my database. I have a pair of replicated servers (Windows 2008 R2) running 5.5.23 and awhile back I had created some triggers to update a date modified field everytime a record gets updated. If definitely works as if I go into the database and update a field, that record shows the latest time.

I've tried doing "Show Triggers" and no records are returned. I've done the same thing in command prompt and no records are returned. There are no records returned from the TRIGGERS table in the information_schema as well.

The triggers were likely created in MySQL 5.1. Could that be the problem?

Thanks!

FIX:
I figured it out. It turned out to be a crazy permissions problem in Windows. The solution? Go into the Users table in MySQL and change any values to "Y" that are set to "N" (I believe: Event_priv, Trigger_priv, Create_tablespace_priv) and restart MySQL. They appear now.

Comment: Where's Users Table? at the moment I'm looking to my MySQL Workbench. I can my schema and within the schema are tables, views, procedure and function. I wanna see also my trigger.